# Represent items on FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm really confuse that How can I represent fragments as a View (Items) in `FragmentPagerAdapter` , I've three `ListFragment` and one `Activity`, How can I represent these fragments to the `FragmentPagerAdapter`? Any ideas ?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like the example [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html) states, no? Just extend `FragmentPagerAdapter` and return each one of your `ListFragment`s in the `getItem()` method:

```
public static class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch(position) {
          case 0: return yourFragment1;
          case 1: return yourFragment2;
          case 2: return yourFragment3;
          default: return yourFragment1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry if I ask this simple question because I'm really new in this section , my first fragment name is "F1" , If I wanna return this fragment should I do this : case 0: return F1; ? Thanks

Comment: Yes, replace `yourFragmentN` with the actual fragments you want to be in each position.